# String is to Substring, as ArrayList is to?

Tags: arraylist, substring, java

In Java, and many other languages, one can grab a subsection of a string by saying something like `String.substring(begin, end)`. My question is, Does there exist a built-in capability to do the same with Lists in Java that returns a sublist from the original?

Comment: I’d guess `slice`. Does Java have that? Or `subList`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method is called [`subList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-) and [exists for both array and linked lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-). Beware that the list it returns is backed by the existing list so updating the original one will update the slice.

Comment: Ooh, thanks for the warning. I really hate all this Java "by reference" crap.

Comment: @QuinnMcHugh Remember that you can construct a new list by passing the slice to the constructor. This will force a copy.

Comment: @Quinn: it's really a view not a clone. If you want to clone that slice, then you have to copy it into a new object. It's really not related to references.

Comment: @hexafraction I know, I' just prefer that I not have to say `object = new Object(other)`. `object = other`, seems logical enough to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the List API: [List#subList(int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (can't figure out how to get the link working....)

Be warned, though, that this is a *view* of the underlying list, so if you change the original list, you'll change the sublist, and the semantics of the sublist is undefined if you structurally modify the original list. So I suppose it isn't strictly what you're looking for...

If you want a structurally independent subsection of the list, I believe you'll have to do something like:

```
ArrayList<something> copy = new ArrayList<>(oldList.subsection(begin, end));
```

However, this will retain references to the original objects in the sublist. You'll probably have to manually clone everything if you want a completely new list.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called **sublist** and can be found here in the javadocs

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int), int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subList(start, end)`

```
ArrayList<String> arrl = new ArrayList<String>();
//adding elements to the end
arrl.add("First");
arrl.add("Second");
arrl.add("Third");
arrl.add("Random");
arrl.add("Click");
System.out.println("Actual ArrayList:"+arrl);
List<String> list = arrl.subList(2, 4);
System.out.println("Sub List: "+list);
```

**Ouput** :

```
Actual ArrayList:[First, Second, Third, Random, Click]
Sub List: [Third, Random]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to make a new method if you want it to be exactly like substring is to `String`.

```java
public static List<String> sub(List<String> strs, int start, int end) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(); //Make a new empty ArrayList with String values
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { //From start inclusive to end exclusive
        ret.add(strs.get(i)); //Append the value of strs at the current index to the end of ret 
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<String> sub(List<String> strs, int start) {
    List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(); //Make a new empty ArrayList with String values
    for (int i = start; i < strs.size(); i++) { //From start inclusive to the end of strs
        ret.add(strs.get(i)); //Append the value of strs at the current index to the end of ret 
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If `myStrings` is an `ArrayList` of the following `Strings`: `{"do","you","really","think","I","am","addicted","to","coding"}`, then `sub(myStrings,1,6)` would return `{"you", "really", "think", "I", "am"}` and `sub(myStrings,4)` would return `{"I", "am", "addicted", "to", "coding"}`. Also by doing `sub(myStrings, 0)` it would rewrite `myStrings` as a new `ArrayList` which could help with referencing problems.